# continuously run a bash script

Tags: bash

```
{ while IFS=';' read  u1 p1 u2 p2; do
            imapsync/imapsync --usecache --host1 secure.emailsrvr.com --user1 "$u1" --password1 "$p1" \
                     --host2 imap.gmail.com --ssl2 --user2 "$u2" --password2 "$p2" ...
     done ; } < users1-33.txt
```

How can I continuously run this script so that when it completes it just starts over again?

Answer (score 4):

Many UNIXy systems have a tool called [`watch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_%28Unix%29) that will repeatedly execute a command (by default every 2 seconds). While `watch` is not a standard POSIX tool, if you have or can install it it is a very simple way to achieve essentially what you're asking for. Put your code in a file and *watch* it thus:

```
watch bash -c your_script
```

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping it in a function and iterating over it.

```
function go()
{
    { while IFS=';' read  u1 p1 u2 p2; do
            imapsync/imapsync --usecache --host1 secure.emailsrvr.com --user1 "$u1" --password1 "$p1" \
                     --host2 imap.gmail.com --ssl2 --user2 "$u2" --password2 "$p2" ...
     done ; } < users1-33.txt

}

while true
do
    go
done
```

Or you can reference `go()` from another file:

```
   #!/bin/sh

   . /the/original/source_file.sh

   go
```

Answer (score 1):

have you considered putting the script in your crontab to run every minute?

so on a debian based system. (ubuntu)

`crontab -e`

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/scriptToRun.sh
```

would have the script run every minute

[More on Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: considered this and wouldn't it just run the script every minute and not when it was complete and then start over.

Comment: it would, you can up the time, but I guess it really depends on the purpose of the script. `Cron` may not be the ideal solution. For example when you need the script to interact with a user, but if you just want to run the script ad infinitum `cron` is really there for you.